# Mapinfo appending TAB file error - multiple points appearing in the same location

Tags: mapinfo, table, tab

I have two TAB files with identical table structures and when appending one to the other all appended points get placed in one location, however when I append them the other way round it works fine. Both have identical projections and table structures. Any idea what causes this so I can look out for it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It could be different coordsys, the bounds part. Try to export to MIF and inspect, if it is the same.